# Multiprocessing Code not producing results

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am running the below code in Python. The code shows the example of how to use multiprocessing in Python. But it is not printing the result (line 16), Only the dataset (line 9) is getting printed and the kernel keeps on running. I am of the opinion that the results should be produced instantly as the code is using various cores of the cpu through multiprocessing so fast execution of the code should be there. Can someone tell what is the issue??

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def square(x):
    # calculate the square of the value of x
    return x*x

if __name__ == '__main__':

    # Define the dataset
    dataset = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14]

    # Output the dataset
    print ('Dataset: ' + str(dataset)) # Line 9

    # Run this with a pool of 5 agents having a chunksize of 3 until finished
    agents = 5
    chunksize = 3
    with Pool(processes=agents) as pool:
        result = pool.map(square, dataset, chunksize)

    # Output the result
    print ('Result:  ' + str(result))  # Line 16
```

Comment: "the kernel keeps on running" do you run this is a bare Python process, or e.g. via Jupyter?

Comment: I cannot reproduce the issue when executing the code directly via ``python3``. I get ``Result:  [1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81, 100, 121, 144, 169, 196]`` practically immediately.

Comment: I tried your code in my Jupyter notebook and it works fine. I would advise updating your question with environment (unix, windows, ...), python-environment (jupyter, colab, shell, script, ...). If you are using a jupyter notebook also add its version, and the what kernel you are using.

Comment: @Marco Necci I am running the above code in python3, jupyter notebook and in Windows 10

Comment: @ MisterMiyagi via jupyter

Comment: What version of jupyter? What version of python (3.6.0, 3.6.1, ..., 3.9.1)? are you using a virtual environment?

Comment: @Marco Necci the python version is 3.6.4

Comment: @MisterMiyagi In which version of python have u got the result ??

Comment: When you run under Jupyter under Windows (is that your situation?), you need to move your worker function (`square` in this case) to an external file and import it to the file that is creating the pool. By the way, when you execute `map`, an appropriate default `chunksize` value will be computed for you based on the number jobs being submitted, which is the size of the *iterable* argument. To compute that size, it may be necessary to convert the iterable to a list, which is not always desirable. But yours is already a list, so there is no downside to allowing the pool to compute this for you.

Comment: When you have a chunksize of 3 so that each of the 5 processes has approximately 3 jobs in its queue (which accounts for all of the submitted jobs), what would happen if one of the processes happened to have 3 quick and easy jobs and processed its jobs very quickly and had no more work to do while each of the other 4 processes still had 3 jobs to complete? One processor would be completely idle for the remainder of the job processing. So a large chunksize is efficient in it reduces the number of shared memory transfers and a processor is not waiting for a transfer to complete. (...more...)

Comment: But it may not be utilizing the processors to their fullest extent.

Comment: @SimrandeepBahal I get the expected results on 3.6.9 and 3.8.5 on MacOS. I don't have any other Python version available at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

You are running under Windows. Look at the console output where you started up Jupyter. You will see 5 instances (you have 5 processes in your pool) of:

> AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'square' on <module '**main**' (built-in)>

You need to put your worker function in a file, for instance, `workers.py`, in the same directory as your Jupyter code:

**workers.py**

```
def square(x):
    # calculate the square of the value of x
    return x*xdef square(x):
```

Then remove the above function from your cell and instead add:

```
import workers
```

and then:

```
with Pool(processes=agents) as pool:
    result = pool.map(workers.square, dataset, chunksize)
```

**Note**

See my comment(s) to your post concerning the `chunksize` argument to the `Pool` constructor. The default `chunksize` for the `map` method when `None` is calculated more or less as follows based on the `iterable` argument:

```
if not hasattr(iterable, '__len__'):
    iterable = list(iterable)

if chunksize is None:
    chunksize, extra = divmod(len(iterable), len(self._pool) * 4)
    if extra:
        chunksize += 1
```

So I mispoke in one deatil: Regardless of whether you specify a `chunksize` or not, `map` will convert your *iterable* to a `list` if it needs to in order to get its length. But essentially the default `chunksize` used is the ceiling of the number of jobs being submitted divided by 4 times the pool size.

Answer (score 0):

There is a known bug in older versions of python and Windows10 https://bugs.python.org/issue35797

It occurs when using multiprocessing through venv.
Bugfix is released in Python 3.7.3.

Comment: So what should I do now ? How to resolve this issue?

Comment: I am running in windows 10 and python version 3.8.5

Comment: In a comment above you said you were running python 3.6.4. If that's the case try installing a version of python later than 3.7.3. If the error persists, you need to provide the minimum amount of data required to reproduce your bug as no one could reproduce it until now.

Comment: @ MarcoNecci I have tried to run the code above on both these python versions, but the same problem persists.